# How to pass OAuth2 access token for get request?

Tags: python, request

I cannot figure out how to pass my retrieved access token to the get requests without manual copy and paste. I tried already doing:

```
#get token

access_token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://XXX.de/api/token', auth=auth)

hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)}
```

But then I get error 401.

If I copy and paste the code manually into the below format, it works:

```
hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ed361d11111111351e43c685bbda7229407b290d'}
```

This is how I get it from `oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://XXX.de/api/token', auth=auth)`:

```
{'access_token': 'ea00be2538ebccc051c66f392ee313797549de04', 'expires_in': 3600, 'token_type': 'Bearer', 'scope': None, 'expires_at': 1559749057.8817663}
```

What am I doing wrong? Still fairly new to requests..

Comment: access_token['access_token']

Answer (score 2):

It's a dictionary:

```
access_token = {'access_token': 'ea00be2538ebccc051c66f392ee313797549de04'}
```

Vs:

```
access_token["access_token"] = 'ea00be2538ebccc051c66f392ee313797549de04'
```

Comment: for some reason I was getting the error Non hashable type earlier, but now its working. I came to the conclusion that its not that easy. Apparantly it is.. Thanks!